# Why can I not select my action as an inline action?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

I want to change the assignee property with an inline action but I cannot seem to select the action I created in the dropdown. Why is my action not showing up?

I added images showing the action configuration for reference.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select actions for inline actions that can have more than one object as their input or that do not have a default value defined for the object property you want it to change.
[image]

[image]

With the above configurations, you can see that the action shows up as an option for the inline editing.
[image]